# Set Webpage to have min-width of 1024px

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a webpage that uses bootstrap, Angular 2x, Scss. I want to have the webpage layout **stop being responsive when at 1024px**. If the user resizes the page below 1024 the browswer should then allow the user to scroll horizontally.

How do I do this?

I have tried:

```
html,body {
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing it with Bootstrap. They provide good instructions and it takes only a few minutes. [See these directions](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)